# span within td doesn't generate properly

Tags: html, css

```
<tr>
                    <td>abc <span>123</span></td>
                    <td>another td</td>
                    <td>another td</td>
                    </tr>
```

Why my above code the span of the first td doesn't generate properly?

I want to have the result like this

```
=============================================
abc       =   another td   =   another td   =
123       
=============================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css **`display`** property to archive this,
view this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v7db3mp/1/)**

#### CSS

```
td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
td span {
    display:block;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>abc <span>123</span></td>
        <td>another td</td>
        <td>another td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ah the default behavior of span is display:inline, so just set it to display block? right?

Comment: Yeah only set `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

Using a span tag does not deliver a result like you want. You need to have CSS rule for that.

add the following CSS to your page,

```css
td {
    width: 100px;
}

td span {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: block;
}
```

This sets a width for  elements and the span is used to break the text line and move it to the next line.